# How does the tct command work under the hood?

Tags: debugging, x86-64, windbg

The windbg command [tct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/tct--trace-to-next-call-or-return-) executes a program until it reaches a `call` instruction or a `ret` instruction. I am wondering how the debugger implements this functionality under the hood.

I could imagine that the debugger scans the instructions from the current instructions for the next `call` or `ret` and sets according breakpoints on the found instructions. However, I think this is unlikely because it would also have to take into account `jmp` instructions so that there are an arbitrary number of possible `call` or `ret` instructions where such a breakpoint would have to be set.

On the other hand, I wonder if the x86/x64 CPU provides a functionality that raises an exception to be caught by the debugger whenever the CPU is about to process a `call` or `ret` instruction. Yet, I have not heard of such a functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that it single-steps repeatedly, until the next instruction is a call or ret, instead of trying to figure out where to set a breakpoint.  (Which in the general case could be as hard as solving the Halting Problem.)

It's possible it could optimize that by scanning forward over "straight line" code and setting a breakpoint on the next `jmp`/`jcc`/`loop` or other control-transfer instruction (e.g. `xabort`), and also catching signals/exceptions that could transfer control to an SEH handler.

I'm also not aware of any HW support for breaking on a certain type of instruction or opcode: [the x86 debug registers DR0..7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register) allow hardware breakpoints at code addresses without rewriting machine code to `int3`, and also hardware watchpoints (to trap data load/store to a specific address or range of addresses). But not filtering by opcode.

Comment: The BTF control in the IA32_DEBUGCTL MSR causes a single-step break on every control transfer instruction.

Comment: @prl: Oh neat, sounds like it was designed for exactly this kind of purpose, to speed through straight-line code while still single-stepping.  https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-585.html extracts a page from vol.3 that describes it.